# QGIS Raster moving when Majority filter

Tags: raster, filter

I'm running QGIS 2.01 Dufour on Linux Mint. Data & project are WGS84.
I'm trying to smooth a grid & following other posts here I've used the Majority filter.  This is looking helpful, but the resulting grid is some 70km WSW of the original.

There aren't any other settings so I'm not sure what's happening & how to correct it.